# How to remove fields from Laravel Notification response object

Tags: laravel, notifications

I would like my laravel notification to only send the fileds I declare in the `toBroadcast` function.

At the moment the output from this is:

```php
public function toBroadcast($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'message' => 'message stuff'
            'subject' => 'subject stuff'
        ];
    }
```

gives

```js
Object { 
    message: 'message stuff',
    subject: 'subject stuff',
    uuid:     { SOME_UUID }
    type:     { app\Notifications\NOTIFICATION_NAME }
}
```

Specifically, how do I remove `uuid` and `type` from response?

Comment: Why do you need to remove it? It's just metadata for the client code to use.